# Method Post Return Null Parameter

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, rest

I'm creating a Web API with VB.NET MVC.
The GET method works perfectly.
But the POST method returns "null" even without any treatment in it, does anyone know what it can be?

I have a controller inside the controller folder

My Code

```
Public Function Post(<FromBody> value As String) As String
Return value
End Function
```

[image: Return PostMan]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to decorate the method with the HttpPost Attribute for it to work:

```
<HttpPost()>
Public Function Post(<FromBody> value As String) As String
   Return value
End Function
```

Comment: I'm calling through the Chorme app, which makes a call to my page as pictured.
It returns null without parameter.
But if I set a constant, return the value of the constant

Comment: So you are passing in null and getting back null? That probably makes sense doesn't it?

Comment: I pass any string and I get null